# cordova - sso on multiple hybrid applications

Tags: android, ios, cordova, single-sign-on, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a situation here to develop multiple (3 in my case) Hybrid applications all which needs user authentication. All the apps are under a SSO.
I want to achieve the following.

1. When any app for first time is opened user should be shown logic
   screen where he enters credentials and is authenticated.
2. When user opens another apps then as he already signed in previous
   app he should be directly taken to home screen without again asking
   for credentials.

Comment: post what you have done ?

Comment: i am actually looking for a cordova plugin which can save logged info which can be used in multiple applications

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Hi @Sandeep did you ever got the answer. I would like to know the solution. I am also in the same situation.